Exercise about independence of events
Given three events $A,B,C$ such that $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\cap B)P(C)$, and the equality also holds if we change any event to it's complement, for example $P(A^C\cap B\cap C)=P(A^c\cap B)P(C)$.
I need to prove/disprove whether A and C are independant or not. If not, I need to give a counter/example.
My intuition says it's a proof since there are too many constraints, but I don't know where to start.
Many thanks to the answerers.

$P(A \cap C) = P(A \cap C \cap B) + P(A \cap C \cap B^C) = P(A \cap B)P(C) + P(A \cap B^C)P(C) = (P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)P(C) = P(A)P(C)$

Alright that works. Thanks. I forgot about the complete probability formula.
